# Registering NHibernate ISession as SingleInstance in Autofac

Tags: c#, nhibernate, autofac

Is there a harm in creating one instance of an NHibernate.ISession implementation in a windows service that is rarely restarted? I don't have a great understanding ISession, but from what I understand, an instance of ISession implementation holds reference to transactions which can be disposed off as soon as I commit my changes

```
using (ITransaction trans = MyISession.BeginTransaction())
{
 ...
trans.Commit();
}
```

When I check code samples online, implementation ISession using autofac is almost always set as InstancePerLifetimeScope(). Which effectively means that the instance would be disposed as soon as it comes out of the context that it was created in (for example an HTTP request ).

Can someone enlighten me on the harm (if any) of registering nhibernate as single instance in autofac for a long running windows process?

```
builder.Register(c => new MyIsessionFactory.OpenSession()).As<ISession>().SingleInstance();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A session keeps track of all the entities and collections it has loaded or even referenced.

Keeping a session open for all the lifetime of your app results in:

- Extremely high memory usage
- Extremely slow operations (scanning the list of loaded entities, which is done automatically by many operations, takes very long when there are too many)
- Impossibility to recover from errors, as the session state becomes corrupted when there is one

Comment: Once it commits a transaction wouldn't the session stop tracking the changes that it just committed? If yes, why would the memory usage go up?

Comment: No, it will not. NHibernate tracks entities, not changes. When flushing, it checks the current state against a snapshot.